# Why d/dx(sin^2(x)) results in sin(2x)?

Tags: calculus

can anyone explain to me why this equation results in sin(2x):

d/dx(sin^2(x))

u = sin^2

v = sin(x)

But in my view this should be like:

u = sin^2

v = x

Why there is another sin(x) when there are already sin^2 in u?

Best regards

Comment: Try reading your your own post above and notice how the software has formatted your text.

Comment: Also try $f(g(x))=\sin^2(x),f(x)=x^2, g(x)=\sin(x)\implies \frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{\not{dg}}\frac{ \not{dg}}{dx}$

Comment: Of course $u=\sin^2 x$ and $v=x$ is also correct.  But that does not help in differentiating $\sin^2 x$, since $dv/dx = 1$ and $du/dv$ is what you want to compute in the first place.

Comment: $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$

Answer (score 1):

The chain rule tells us that for two functions $f$ and $g$ (under the appropriate differentiability conditions) we have that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).$$

For the functions given by $\sin^2 x$ we can identify the parts here by

$$f(x)=x^2, \quad g(x)=\sin x,$$

because notice that

$$f(g(x))=\left(\sin x\right)^2=\sin^2 x.$$

Thus, by applying the chain rule and remarking that

$$f'(x)=2x, \quad g'(x)=\cos x,$$

we get that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin^2 x=2\sin x \cos x=\sin 2x.$$

Another way to do it would be to, instead of the chain rule, use the product rule, as we do have a product of two sine functions. So, with $g$ defined as before, remark that

$$g(x)\cdot g(x)=\sin x \cdot \sin x = \sin^2 x.$$

Now the product rule tells us that the derivative of a product of two functions $f$ and $g$ (not necessarily the same as we defined) is given by

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigl(f(x)\cdot g(x)\bigr)=f'(x) g(x)+f(x)g'(x).$$

Applying this to our problem we have that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin^2 x=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\bigl(\sin x \cdot \sin x\bigr)=\cos x \sin x + \sin x \cos x = 2\sin x\cos x=\sin 2x.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you check that $$\begin{align}\sin^2x & = \frac{\sin^2x+\sin^2x}2 \\ \\
& = \frac{1 - \cos^2x+\sin^2x}2 \\ \\
& = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}2\end{align}$$
you'll get
$$\begin{align}
\frac d{dx} \sin^2x & = \frac d{dx}\frac{1 - \cos(2x)}2 \\ \\
 & = \frac 12 \frac d{dx}(1 - \cos(2x)) \\ \\
 & = \frac 12 \left(\frac d{dx} 1 - \frac d{dx}\cos(2x)\right) \\ \\
 & = \frac 12 \left(0 - \frac d{dx}\cos(2x)\right) \\ \\
 & = \frac 12 \left(- \frac d{d2x}\cos(2x)\cdot\frac {d2x}{dx}\right) \\ \\
 & = \frac 12 \left(- (-\sin(2x))\cdot\frac {d2x}{dx}\right) \\ \\
 & = \frac 12 \left(\sin(2x)\cdot2\right) \\ \\
 & = \sin(2x)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I suggest first writing $\sin^2x=(\sin x)^2$ to more clearly identify nested functions; we see that applying sine is the first operation and squaring is the second operation. Hence, we may write

$$(\sin x)^2=f(g(x)),$$

for $f(z)=z^2,g(z)=\sin z.$ Then $f'(z)=2z,g'(z)=\cos z.$

Thus, chain rule gives $$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))&=f'(g(x))g'(x)\\
&=(2\sin x)\cos x\\
&=\sin 2x,\end{align}$$

the last line following from the double angle identity for sine.